# Problem with photo on anonymous user page

Tags: nodes

I uploaded an article with a photo to my website. The photo is showing for administrators, but not for anonymous users.

What do I need to do to make sure the photo displays for all users?

Comment: There are many things that might cause this. Is the server 403-ing the image URL? Is it showing up on the admin theme but not the default theme? Are you using a per-field-permission module like [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

Comment: Shawn is correct, we need some more information here as to the error that you're seeing. Does the image display in the HTML DOM?

Comment: I was able to solve the image problem by clearing cache